# Mongoose .find() is returning an object with keys that look like indices of an array instead of an array of objects

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, fetch

I am making a REST API using MERN and React keeps telling me that .map and .forEach are not functions for my getAll return data. I console logged the data type of my response and got this:

```
0: {_id: "5fd2cb4e5f9960344b19fcdf", projectName: "test 1", description: "new", image: "img.png", __v: 0}
1: {_id: "5fd2cb4e5f9960344b19fce0", projectName: "test 1", description: "new", image: "img.png", __v: 0}
2: {_id: "5fd2cb4e5f9960344b19fce1", projectName: "test 1", description: "new", image: "img.png", __v: 0}
3: {_id: "5fd2cb4e5f9960344b19fce2", projectName: "test
```

Here is my controller:

```
async function crochetProject(req, res) {
    try {
        const crochets = await Crochet.find()
        res.json(crochets);
    } catch (err) {
        res.json(err)
    }
}
```

Here is my fetch request:

```
function fetchCrochetData(){
    return fetch(BASE_URL).then(res => res.json()
    )
}
```

I've tried {lean: true}, forcing the data type to an array in both the back and front ends.

I don't know what else I could be doing wrong to get an array of my database items returned.

Comment: please do check in your controller that you are getting array or not! Just make log of crochets and check that! And try to send reponse like res.json({ crochets })